# Fullcalendar drag and drop allday

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar with both normal events and allDay events.

I want to disable the allDay-events from being able to be dragged into normal events in the agenda view.

The allday events have both start-time and end-time set from the begining so I cant check if the endtime is null.

Perhaps there is a way in the eventDrop-function to block this off?

Comment: Can you put this in a jsfiddle or post some code? I want to see how your event data is formatted.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wkKfB/24/
move to the week-view and you can drag an alday event from the top into the agenda-view. This should not be possible.
Ignore the onExternalEventDrop I used another jsfiddle to create my example. Also both events seem to move here, but that isn’t the case in my real calendar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/GPx28/

Some points to note:

- The `allDay` parameter in the `eventDrop` callback *doesn't* represent the event's allDay. It represents the ***slot's*** allDay ability. So, in week view, the top bar will have `allDay` as `true` and the time-slots below will have `allDay` as `false`.
- The `event` parameter in the `eventDrop` callback has the updated date/time. So if you moved an event from the allDay slot to the 6:30 AM slot, the start of the event in this callback will actually say **6:30:00**. So, I stored the allDay parameter for the dragged event in a variable at drag-start (through the `eventDragStart` callback)
- The `id` attribute of an event determines if it is a repeatable event. In your fiddle the allDay event and the normal event both had the same id - which will complicate your dragging operations. Avoid this if you can.
- Lastly, I think you knew this, but the correct callback after an event is dropped is called `eventDrop` - not just drop.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

A little late but I just had a similar problem.  Some of my allDay events needed to be fixed, others did not.  My solution was to add a user defined value against each event called "forceAllDay" and set it to either true or false.

Then in the event drop section added this:

```
eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
    if (event.forceAllDay && !allDay) {
        revertFunc();
    } else {
        if (!confirm('Move event?')) {
            revertFunc();
        } else {
            // UPDATE DATABASE
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if endtime is null with moment. Hope it helps

```
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
    var m = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.end);

    if (!m.hasTime() && !event.allDay)
        revertFunc(); 
    else {

    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

As per their latest API 2.xx you can do it like this:

```
var draggedEventIsAllDay
var eventDragStart = function(ev) {
    draggedEventIsAllDay = ev.allDay;
};

var eventDrop = function(ev, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    var data = delta._data,
        dayDelta = data.days,
        minuteDelta = data.minutes,
        allDay;

    var start = jQuery.fullCalendar.moment(ev.start.format('MM-DD-YYYY'));

    if (start.hasTime()) {
        allDay = false;
    } else {
        allDay = true;
    }


    if (!allDay && draggedEventIsAllDay || allDay && !draggedEventIsAllDay) {
        revertFunc();
    }
};
```